# Extract image src from <img>tag in android

Tags: android, html

i have this img tag from server. can anyone tell code to extract image link from the below tag.

```
> <img id="prescription_image"
> onClick=showPrescriptionDetails("34173cb38f07f89ddbebc2ac9128303f")
> onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"
> src="http://patient/1409210919.png" width="20" height="20">
```

thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
int start = tags.indexOf("src=\"") + 5;
int end = tags.indexOf("\"", start);

String src = tags.substring(start, end);
```

Comment: Possible handling for uppercase notation would be useful here I think.

Comment: @Jitsu Handling for non existing src attribute would be useful also. However OP showed us an example of the input and didn't say anything about the possibility of it changing, hence my answer.

Answer (score 3):

More fool proof using regex:

```
String html = "<img SRC=\"whatever\">whatever</img>"
String imgRegex = "<[iI][mM][gG][^>]+[sS][rR][cC]\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(imgRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);

if (m.find()) {
    String imgSrc = m.group(1);
}
```

This will take care of possible upper/lower case issues, which the previous solution has, and also tries to handle more unusual cases.