# Android Image URL from HTML

Tags: android, html, json, image, src

I'm developing Android app. There is a json, which contains field "thumb".
"thumb" is a string with html code.

```
"thumb":"<img width=\"1280\" height=\"570\" src=\"http:\/\/xxx.xxx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/profesor--kosmos.jpg\" class=\"attachment-medium-size wp-post-image\" alt=\"Hello World" \/>"
```

The question is how to extract image url from this string to obtain smth like this:

```
String url = "http:\/\/xxx.xxx.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/11\/profesor--kosmos.jpg"
```

Task is not to download image or display it. Just to obtain URL.

Comment: jsoup or any xml parser would do. (please no regex)

Comment: With String:indexOf() and String:substring() you can do that in only a few lines. No need for a heavy parser.

Comment: There are already similar questions: [Extract image src from <img>tag in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545370/extract-image-src-from-imgtag-in-android)
[android java get html image tag from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998163/android-java-get-html-image-tag-from-string)

Comment: thanks. indexOf and substring are really the simplest solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using phonegap, you can write this jquery to obtaing URL:

`var stringURL=$('img').attr('src');`