# how to get image url from json string in android to display in image view

Tags: android, json, html, android-layout

Guys this is my json data:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "post": {
    "id": 8,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "android",
    "url": "http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/2016/07/13/android/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "Android",
    "title_plain": "Android",
    "content": "<p>Google&#8217;s Android is shaking up the mobile market in a big way. With Android.</p>\n<p><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-31\" src=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_-300x222.jpg\" alt=\"51KRggHZuzL._SX355_\" width=\"300\" height=\"222\" srcset=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_-300x222.jpg 300w, http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_.jpg 355w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 85vw, 300px\" /> <img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-12\" src=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH-300x232.png\" alt=\"moto\" width=\"300\" height=\"232\" srcset=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH-300x232.png 300w, http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH.png 600w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 85vw, 300px\" /></p>\n",
    "excerpt": "<p>Google&#8217;s Android is shaking up the mobile market in a big way. With Android.  </p>\n",
    "date": "2016-07-13 06:12:00",
    "modified": "2016-07-18 07:12:39"
  }
}
```

In content data I am getting String like this:

```
<p>Google&#8217;s Android is shaking up the mobile market in a big way. With Android.</p>\n<p><img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-31\" src=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_-300x222.jpg\" alt=\"51KRggHZuzL._SX355_\" width=\"300\" height=\"222\" srcset=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_-300x222.jpg 300w, http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/51KRggHZuzL._SX355_.jpg 355w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 85vw, 300px\" /> <img class=\"alignnone size-medium wp-image-12\" src=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH-300x232.png\" alt=\"moto\" width=\"300\" height=\"232\" srcset=\"http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH-300x232.png 300w, http://192.168.1.8/Android/android/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CV2iAeMXIAAQlZH.png 600w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 300px) 85vw, 300px\" /></p>\n
```

So,How I get image url from this String

Comment: is it really JSON ?

Comment: It is String form Json

Comment: It's html, not JSON.

Comment: it is html data.....

Comment: yes,it is a html.it is from my json data

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545370/extract-image-src-from-imgtag-in-android you may find your ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this::

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements element = doc.getAllElements();
        for(Element e: element)
        {
            Elements str = e.getElementsByTag("img");
            for(Element el: str)
            {                
                String src= el.attr("src");
                System.out.println("The src:"+src);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expression to match the `src` attribule from `img` tag.

Try this code,

```
String mydata = "your html string";
String regex = "src\\s*=\\s*\"(.+?)\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
List<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    imgUrls.add(matcher.group(1));
}

//Load imgUrls into ImageViews using some image loader
```

For imageloader you can use [Picasso](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: Please don't use regex for html http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1483663

Comment: @RuslanBes Any alternatives without any external dependencies?

Comment: It is working for One image url but the string contains two image url how will I get it

Comment: Thanks for your support @K Neeraj Lal

Answer (score 0):

```
URL[] urlsimage;
Bitmap[] TBM;

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Response);

urlsimage=new URL[jsonArray.length()];
TBM=new Bitmap[jsonArray.length()];

for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

Image[i]=jsonObject.getString("image");
  if(!Image[i].equals("null"))
  {
      urlsimage[i]=new URL(Image[i]);
      TBM[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlsimage[i].openConnection().getInputStream());
  }
}

img.setImageBitmap(TBM[0]);
```