# How to Parse this non organised xml from DOM

Tags: java, android, dom

How do i parse this Description node?
i need img link and description , and do you think its a correct XML for parsing because for me its not making any sense,

```
 <description><![CDATA[<img width="680" height="538"
    src="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=680" class="attachment-large size-large wp-post-image" alt="" 
    srcset="https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=680 680w,
         https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=1360 1360w, 
        https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=150 150w, 
        https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=300 300w, 
        https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/team1.png?w=768 768w"
         sizes="(max-width: 680px) 100vw, 680px" />&nbsp;
        DogBuddy, a pan-European online marketplace for dog sitting, has closed €5 million in Series A funding, money it plans for further expansion. Backing the London-headquartered startup in this round is existing investor Sweet Capital, the investment fund started by the founders of King.com, and a number of new unnamed private investors. It brings total raised by DogBuddy to €10 million. 
        <a href="https://techcrunch.com/2017/09/21/dogbuddy-2/?ncid=rss">Read More</a>]]></description>
```

I'm using DOM

Comment: where is the description?

Comment: is this the description? _DogBuddy, a pan-European online marketplace for dog sitting, has closed €5 million in Series A funding, money it plans for further expansion. Backing the London-headquartered startup in this round is existing investor Sweet Capital, the investment fund started by the founders of King.com, and a number of new unnamed private investors. It brings total raised by DogBuddy to €10 million._?

Comment: yes this is the description

Comment: @Orvenito do you think this is correct xml for parsing ?

Comment: definitely not. if you can find a way to parse it correctly then you won't have a problem parsing

Comment: then how do i parse it, reading by characters? that will be not a good approach

Comment: did you create that xml? or you just got it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all.**

> and do you think its a correct XML for parsing because for me its not
>   making any sense,

of course it is. you can test here. https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer

**Second**

if this is the final response, then you have the choice of using.

```
android.text.Html; // for html tags
android.text.Html.ImageGetter; // for html image tags parsing
```

classes and **Regex**. hopefully it will be work.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer i'm getting complete xml from https://techcrunch.com/feed/ and i have parsed every thing except the <description> tag so i'm getting this tag as a Node how should i change it according to your answer thanks

Comment: dude... there r many examples.. see.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images

Comment: or for regex.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545370/extract-image-src-from-imgtag-in-android