# How to show video with TextView in Android Studio project?

Tags: java, html, android-studio-3.0

If we can show any image with `textview` with code like this

```
textView.setHtml(item.getContent(), new HtmlHttpImageGetter(textView));
```

So how can I show any videos using `textview` too?

Answer (score 1):

images are static images, videos are different html tags and work differently. As of my knowledge, it is not possible. however you can add a `VideoView` to your project: [click here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Comment: im curious. Why would you add an image to a TextView when there are ImageViews?

Comment: is that the problem,,, the image and video tag is inside of my json content,,, i wanna show it between any text,,

Comment: you could extract the src attribute from the html tag using regex or some different method and then setting the url of the video view to the extracted value

Comment: how can i do that??,,, could be work,, can you give the link of that tutorial or video??

Comment: you can do this for video tags as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545370/extract-image-src-from-imgtag-in-android